# How does band gap vary with the cell volume?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

How does band gap vary with the cell volume? is there a relation?

If the volume is compressed, the interaction between atoms would be more, therefore the perturbation is higher hence the splitting would be more. Is my assumption right?

What is the mathematical background? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume, you take a one-dimensional chain of atoms and compress it.

In order to investigate the bandstructure, you will need to determine the electronic wavefunctions of quantum-mechanically allowed states. If you know your wavefunctions for the initial condition, before you compress your chain of atoms, you need to also scale the solution in order to still fullfill Bloch's theorem.

Thus, the energies of your wavefunctions (and therefore also the width of forbidden regions, meaning bandgaps) will scale with your transformation of the lattice. Compression will therefore result in shorter wavelengths and therefore higher energies.

Hope this helps!